# Send file using socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server application and I want to send a file from this server to some client that is connected to me.

On the client side I don't have any running application, the only thing that  I have is a telnet connection between client and server.

Getting the conection:

```
Socket cliente = null;
client = server.accept();
```

Receiving and sending information:

```
        inClient = client.getInputStream();
        outClient = client.getOutputStream();
        bfClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inClient));
        pwClient = new PrintWriter(outClient, true);
```

The file that I want to send:

```
File flMacro = new File("macro.txt");
```

I have the file path where I want to save it on the client side.

My problem is: how can I send macro.txt that is in my server to the client, specifying the file path where I want to save it, without any client interaction.

Comment: just go ahead, and write file length, then file contents into `outClient`. On client side, act accordingly.

Comment: Victor, I don't have the client side, I mean I don't have a part of my application that is for the client. On the client machine I just open cmd, connect to my server using telnet, send some commands and then wait for the response. Just this.

Comment: Ahh, sorry for misunderstanding. Have you `nc` (netcat) on your client? If yes, you can make it connect to server, then write received contents into file (see `nc` man page for example command for this)

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but what is netcat :/

Comment: Essentially, command-line telnet and some more. So you can just issue command-line like `nc -p severPort serverHost > client_side_macro.txt`.

Comment: The client has connected to you over telnet or you connected to the client?

Comment: Brett, the client connected to me over telnet.

Comment: You are not asking for server side code, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do straight away with java SDK. You would have to use some 3rd party tools, like Ant's [Scp Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html). not sure, though how to call it directly from java.